# Not an answer flag declined for a comment

Tags: discussion

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4407308/2654083) doesn't really answer the question at all. It is really just a comment about the usefulness of the `in` operator. I flagged it as NAA but my flag was declined because there was no evidence to support it. Am I misunderstanding the NAA flag?

Comment: How are the reviewers or the moderators supposed to know that? It looks like an attempt at answering. Raise a custom flag explaining that you feel this is not an answer to the question, but in stead a comment response. Bonus points if you can link to the content it is replying to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would a mod flag be okay?  I just ask as this is something the community can vote on and delete.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That post wouldn't make any sense as a comment; it's not commenting on anything else there.

Comment: NAA is generally for things that are much more blatantly not answers, such as someone trying to ask another question in an answer, or the OP trying to add something else to their question without knowing how to edit it.

Comment: @Servy: agreed. I've looked at it more closely, and as an answer it is a puzzling one, but I don't see what it would be comment to if it is not an answer. I've left some comments on it explaining why I downvoted it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer isn't Not An Answer.  It's a really bad answer (partially stemming from the fact that the question is a really bad question), but it's an answer.  Note that "doesn't contain much information" doesn't make a post not an answer.  Short answers, bad answers, poorly explain answers, unclear answers, etc. are still answers, they're not comments.  Comments aren't where we put poorly explained answers, it's where people post information about how the post they're commenting on can be improved.  If you don't *like* the answer, then downvote it.  That's the appropriate tool for indicating that you don't think an answer is useful.

Comment: I disagree that it is a bad answer. If I come across that answer from google I don't even know what to do with the `in` operator. Do I add it and just hope iterate magic happens? Are there other keywords required? If the mod doesn't know the language well enough to make a determination why interact with the flag

Comment: @fordprefect: that's what makes it an unhelpful answer. It is *still an attempt at answering*, they just did a really bad job at it.

Comment: @fordprefect The fact that it fails to give you enough information to properly answer the question doesn't make it not an attempt to answer the question.  It makes it a *failed* attempt at answering the question (in your opinion).  Not An Answer is for posts that aren't even trying to answer, not for posts that are answering the question but *fail to successfully answer it*.

Comment: I would argue that this still isn't attempting to answer the question it's just a semi useful comment

Comment: Either way thanks for explaining. I will change how I flag

Comment: @fordprefect Like I said in my answer, comments aren't where we put bad answers that fail to provide a useful answer.  An answer isn't a comment just because you don't think it's useful.  If you think it's not useful, downvote it.  That's what downvotes are for.  Flagging a post because you think it's not useful is just going to get you declined flags, and possibly a flag ban if you do it enough.

Comment: @fordprefect: I'm afraid any other flag would also be rejected. There is a standard reject reason: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*.

Comment: @fordprefect "If the mod doesn't know the language well enough to make a determination why interact with the flag"  Mods aren't there to make technical judgements about the quality of a post.  The mechanism for providing technical judgements of the quality of a post are votes.  Mods are there to address issues that *are unrelated to the technical merits of the post*.  In the case of NAA, this means the mods are there to judge if someone isn't even trying to answer the question, not whether or not they succeeded in providing a quality answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Servy thanks. I will update how I manage this